# Why did my Virtualbox vm revert to a snapshot on crash?

Tags: virtualbox

I clicked 'hibernate' in my Linux Virtualbox guest and the screen when dark.

So I closed the window (chose 'power off').  I then restarted the vm and the whole machine had rolled back to its state from two days ago (the last snapshot).  I've lost all my work since then.

What happened? How do I prevent it happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because of a terrible UI design flaw in Virtualbox.

In the 'restore machine state' dialog that pops up if a machine has crashed or you 'paused' it there is checkbox called 'revert to last snapshot' that is checked by default.

So when you click 'ok' you lose your current state.

To stop this happening in the future always remember to untick this box. Or never take snapshots.  Or take daily snapshots.

Comment: Or work on the host and deploy on the guest. I suppose the "UI flaw" is meant for people that want their system to just work, instead of leaving a broken system by default. But I agree this shouldn't happen on hibernation.